# Webview loadurl with GET request and token?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, httpwebrequest, get-request

I'm trying to do basic authentication to view a protected url.
I am doing a GET request to a url with token. When I try to do my get using HttpUrlConnection after that webview display blank;

I tried two way:

1.

```
WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url1) {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(url1);

                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                    String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url.getHost());
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("CRM_USER_AGENT", "crm_app");
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());


                    data = new java.util.Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

                    System.out.println("Data:" + data);

                    urlConnection.getContentType();
                    urlConnection.getContentEncoding();
                    urlConnection.getContentEncoding();

                    urlConnection.disconnect();


                    return new WebResourceResponse("text/html","UTF-8", in);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    return null;
                }


            }
        };


        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.loadUrl(urlAddress);
```

and 2:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
        webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mySingleton = MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity());

        final String token = "Bearer " + mySingleton.getData(Constant.GUEST_TOKEN);


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
                urlAddress = url;
                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", token);
                    HttpResponse httpReponse = client.execute(httpGet);

                    Header contentType = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentType();
                    Header encoding = httpReponse.getEntity().getContentEncoding();
                    InputStream responseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    String contentTypeValue = null;
                    String encodingValue = null;
                    if (contentType != null) {
                        contentTypeValue = contentType.getValue();
                    }
                    if (encoding != null) {
                        encodingValue = encoding.getValue();
                    }
                    return new WebResourceResponse(contentTypeValue, encodingValue, responseInputStream);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //return null to tell WebView we failed to fetch it WebView should try again.
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });

        webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview.loadUrl(urlAddress);
        return view;
    }
```

but couldn't get success and display blank.

How could i achieve the response of an GET request with authentication and after display webpage?

Comment: Did you look at `WebView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword()`?

Comment: @krislarson yes not work for me 